# How to fill area between two averages in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have two arrays representing averages:

```
val1 = [1.1974298934176164, 1.197608384421945, 1.1977147934109091, 1.1979125278671037, 1.1981475340039716, 1.1983540749861616, 1.1988396173314164, 1.1994043067627347, 1.1999790418677156, 1.2007222804957223, 1.2012619384358896, 1.2016847229621008, 1.2020040000740846, 1.2023233878281563, 1.2025751764174386]
val2 = [1.1970508333333332, 1.197240833333333, 1.1974208333333332, 1.1976458333333333, 1.1978491666666666, 1.1980808333333333, 1.1984641666666667, 1.1989441666666667, 1.19948, 1.20015, 1.2006533333333334, 1.2011866666666666, 1.2015658333333332, 1.2020233333333332, 1.2024949999999999]
```

I am drawing them like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(sma12, color="darkred", linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(ema12, color="darkred", linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)
plt.axis('off')
plt.autoscale()
```

This is the result:

[image: Two averages]

What's the easiest way to fill the space between these two averages so that you get something like a ribbon? I was trying to use plt.fill_between() ([matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html)) but i don't have x coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fill_between(x,y1,y2)`, so I specified a list of each. This is what you're looking for.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

val1 = [1.1974298934176164, 1.197608384421945, 1.1977147934109091, 1.1979125278671037, 1.1981475340039716, 1.1983540749861616, 1.1988396173314164, 1.1994043067627347, 1.1999790418677156, 1.2007222804957223, 1.2012619384358896, 1.2016847229621008, 1.2020040000740846, 1.2023233878281563, 1.2025751764174386]
val2 = [1.1970508333333332, 1.197240833333333, 1.1974208333333332, 1.1976458333333333, 1.1978491666666666, 1.1980808333333333, 1.1984641666666667, 1.1989441666666667, 1.19948, 1.20015, 1.2006533333333334, 1.2011866666666666, 1.2015658333333332, 1.2020233333333332, 1.2024949999999999]

plt.fill_between(np.arange(len(val1)), val1, val2, interpolate=False)

plt.axis('off')
plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is the correct and helpful answer. Thank you!